# Deleting an Octopress post in dir "_posts"

Tags: post, blogs, octopress

I have 2 posts on my Octopress site, one of which I'm trying to delete. When I go into the source/_posts directory to delete it it's not there. I tried deploying the site again, (I deploy through github pages), but it's not removing the post. How to get I get this post off my Octopress blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by using the rsync_delete option in the rakefile. It will delete any file that does not exist in the source. Simply update to rsync_delete:true. If you have more files on your site that you don't want to delete which are not located in the source, take a look at [this](http://atomicplayboy.net/blog/2012/12/26/keeping-octopress-clean/) for a thorough explanation of how to exclude these files.